# Why are for loops not allowed in React - JSX?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm trying to understand why this code snippet is not allowed:

```
<tbody>{
for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    <ObjectRow obj={objects[i]} key={i}>
} }
```

and why this one is allowed:

```
<tbody>
    {objects.map(function(object, i){
        return <ObjectRow obj={object} key={i} />;
    })}
</tbody
```

I'm not getting it...
Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the JSX expects anything inside of it to return an object to be displayed. A for loop does not return anything, but map does.

You could make a for loop if you had something like this

```
const getObjects = () => {
  const objs = []
  for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objs.push(<ObjectRow obj={objects[i]} key={i}>)
  }

  return objs;
}

<tbody>{getObjects()}
```

Answer (score 7):

In JSX, you have to pass expression (produces a value) into curly braces. However for loop is a statement (performs an action).

Furthermore, what you have tried in for-loop is not a valid javascript.

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop doesn't return any value. The `for` loop simply *does something* to each item in an array.

On the other hand, `map` returns a **new array** of React elements.

For instance:

```
function giveMeAnArrayPlease() {
  // Doesn't do anything, just loops through the array
  var array = ['Hey', 'Hi', 'What's up'];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i];
  }
}
```

VS

```
function giveMeAnArrayPlease() {
  // Returns a nice uppercase array
  var array = ['Hey', 'Hi', 'What's up'];
  return array.map(word => word.toUpperCase());
}
```

Map *returns* a new array with all of the words uppercased. React can take an array of elements and turn it into elements, such as in the example, but it cannot take 'undefined' and turn it into an element.